# Laravel 5.5 close Postgresql database connection

Tags: database, postgresql, laravel-5, pdo, php-7.2

I searched on web but not found a solution to my problem.

My environment:

- Laravel 5.5
- PHP 7.2
- Postgresql 12.3
- Ubuntu 18.4

My problem is that `DB::disconnect()` doesn't close the connection.

My project have multiple database connection to Postgre and many jobs that use this connection.

Inside the job I want to disconnect from the default connection and connect to a specific one.

So if I run multiple times the job, it will create multiple connection and never close the old one.

I tried with `DB::reconnect()`, `DB::disconnect()` and `DB::purge()`, but the connection still open.

I read that the PDO connection is close when all references are set to `null`, it is possible that the framework keep some reference to the PDO connection and so it will never close?

I tried to make a simple script like:

```
DB::connect('some_connection'); 
DB::disconnect('some_connection');
```

But I can see the connection open on my database.

Any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps the connection pool? That would be a feature.

Comment: Would be a nice feature, but in my case is enough to close old connection.